# Why does Glimpse Host section show multiple renders for the same Controller.Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, glimpse

Just trying to understand what it means to see `Render: DealerCustomers.CustomerManager` multiple times as in the screenshot below:

[image: Host Timings with trivial]

And why don't these times contribute to the 42ms action time? Obviously, we are trying to understand some performance issues.

Comment: Can you include the screen shot for when you click "Show Trivial"? My guess is that you have a loop that is calling the render multiple times. Additionally, could you include the screen shot from the execution tab?

Comment: Updated screenshot to show the trivial timings. My best guess is that those additional timings are partial views off the main controller, but they show with the original view names, for some reason.